# How to upgrade nginx from 1.6.3 to 1.8.x on CentOS 6

Tags: nginx, centos

I am on CentOS 6, nginx 1.6.3

```
$nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.6.3
```

And I want to upgrade nginx to 1.8 because the [add_header [always] directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) is needed

I was following https://webtatic.com/packages/nginx18/ to do the upgrade but got the following error

```
$yum list nginx*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.service.networklayer.com
 * epel: free.nchc.org.tw
 * extras: mirrors.service.networklayer.com
 * updates: mirrors.service.networklayer.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Installed Packages
nginx16.x86_64       1.6.3-1.w6       @webtatic
Available Packages
nginx18.x86_64       1.8.0-1.w6       webtatic
```

When I run `yum install -y nginx18`, it gives

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/sbin/nginx from install of nginx18-1.8.0-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx16-1.6.3-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/nginx/nginx.so from install of nginx18-1.8.0-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx16-1.6.3-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/nginx.pm from install of nginx18-1.8.0-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx16-1.6.3-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man3/nginx.3pm.gz from install of nginx18-1.8.0-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nginx16-1.6.3-1.w6.x86_64

Error Summary
```

Can someone kindly guide me through the correct steps of upgrading nginx from 1.6.3 to 1.8 on CentOS 6? Ideally without `yum remove`-ing nginx16 and then installing nginx18 which would cause server downtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nginx package is not designed to have multiple versions installed at the same time, you need to uninstall the old version and install the new one:

```
$ yum remove nginx16
$ yum install nginx18
```

Alternatively, you can try

```
 $ yum install yum-plugin-replace
 $ yum replace nginx16 --replace-with=nginx18
 $ service nginx restart
```

But better test it on a test server first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm definitely using your suggestion if server downtime cannot be avoided.

Comment: you will need to restart nginx server anyway.

Comment: While I look forward to other possibilities, it is the best option I got for now